# Unable to create JVM using jni_CreateJavaVM API in Fedora 8

Tags: java-native-interface, fedora, php-extension

I have created a PHP extension (written in C). I am using JNI to make java calls.

I use jni_CreateJavaVM to create JVM. This works fine in:

- IIS (windows)
- Apache (windows)
- PHP CLI (Fedora 8)

But when I try to load the same extension from Apache (in Fedore 8), the create jni_ CreateJavaVM return JNI _ERROR. I call jni _CreateJavaVM from PHP _RINIT _FUNCTION.

I though that it might be that my extension cannot loacate libjvm.so. So in the same code, before calling jni_ CreateJavaVM, I tried to load the libjvm.so library, and it was successful. Only when I call the jni function, it returns JNI_ERROR.

I used LD_ LOAD function to load libjvm.so. After loading the library I obtain pointer to jni_ CreateJavaVM method which is successful. Only when I make a call, using the pointer or direct jni_ CreateJavaVM call, it returns -1.

Is there any way to find out what went wrong during initialization?

Platfrom: Fedora 8
Java: Jdk 1.5 update 8
Php: Php version 5.3

Here is the code that I have written to initialize JVM.

```
typedef jint (JNICALL CreateJavaVM_t)(JavaVM **pvm, void **env, void *args);
typedef jint (JNICALL* GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs_t)(void*);

CreateJavaVM_t *CreateJavaVM;
GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs_t GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs;
JavaVM* jvm;
JNIEnv* env;

void create_vm(void)
{       
    JavaVMOption vm_options;
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    int retval = 0;

    dl_handle = DL_LOAD("libjvm.so");       
    //The call is successful and I get the handle

    CreateJavaVM = (CreateJavaVM_t*)DL_FETCH_SYMBOL(dl_handle, "JNI_CreateJavaVM");
    //The call is successful and I get pointer to function

    GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs = (GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs_t)DL_FETCH_SYMBOL(dl_handle,"JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs");
    //The call is successful and I get pointer to function

    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_4;
    vm_args.options = &vm_options;
    vm_args.nOptions = 0;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_FALSE;

(*GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs)(&vm_args);

    retval = CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void **)&env, &vm_args);
    //The retval is -1.

    //And if I do
    retval = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    //This also returns -1
}
```

Comment: How did you try to load libjvm.so? by using absolute path? Or just the file name and it picked up from PATH env variable?

Comment: I have created a soft link of libjvm.so in usr/lib. I passed only the file name.

Comment: Did you try putting path to libjvm.so inside the orginal JRE structure in LD_LIBRARY_PATH instead of a symbolic link. jvm uses relative path from its actual location to find other files required. Atleast in windows it expects! Worth giving a try.

Comment: Yes I have the following path set in LD_LIBRARY_PATH
jdk1.5.0/jre/lib/i386/client

There was a small misunderstanding, so I am going to change the question, and also include some sample code.

Comment: No, still not working. Although I have set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, my program is unable to load the libjvm.so. But when I make a soft link in /usr/lib/ it is able to load libjvm.so but jni_CreateJavaVM fails.

Comment: You get a pointer to JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs but do not call it to initialize vm_args.

Comment: I changed the source and used JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs but still the same reuslt. It runs fine on Php Cli, but fails when I try to from Apache.

I have also updated the code I have posted here.

Answer (score 0):

This question is five years old. I stumbled across it while researching about the status of the function JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs on different platforms. It seems to be a function that is unnecessary to call, and may even be deprecated on some platforms. But using the [current documentation from Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) (for Java 1.7 and 1.8) as the primary reference, it's clear that the above code has a serious bug. Only the vm_args.version field should be set before the call to JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs. All of the other fields should be set after calling JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs.

But on most platforms you can probably simply remove the call to JNI_GetDefaultJavaVMInitArgs.